# JQuery Modal Popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm attempting to have a modalpopup appear once a button has been clicked on an asp.net page.

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestFile.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestFile" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

                function fnmodalpopup() {
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
});
        </script>
    </head>

    <!--Misc functions for operations -->
    <script runat="server" type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
        <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
    </div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

I'm trying to create a dialog box exactly like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal, but triggered in an asp.net form by clicking a button. The page flashes and nothing appears.

Any feedback would be very helpful!

Comment: What is your problem? What is your question

Comment: Where are you setting your variable `$dialog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use OnClientClick event and then prevent the postback with **return false** like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return fnmodalpopup()" />

function fnmodalpopup() {   
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Edit:** 
I've changed OnClientClick="**return** fnmodalpopup()"
Now it works OK (at least when I tested it).

Just curious, why do you want to use server-side component if you don't want to create postback? If there is no situation when this button have to do postback, perhaps it would be better to use html button tag (or any other html tag and catch 'click' event with jQuery). It doesn't matter if you use asp.net controls on the rest of the page.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, just reset original page position. No popup.

Comment: Alright, it works now. Someone please vote Goran up (as I don't have enough reputation to). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.Net, If you drag a script manager onto the page, and put the button within a update panel - Content Template tag, then also this works properly. Because the Ajax update panel prevents the postback by default under the covers in asp.net, the button's OnClientClick works properly to show the jquery popup. But this is useful mainly in cases where the button is part of a control set providing a rich client side experience, rather than posting back all the time (e.g. In a usercontrol that provides an interactive client side control panel).

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

to:

```
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="fnmodalpopup();" />
```

then:

```
function fnmodalpopup() {   
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Do I have to put the button in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: no, the button will work anywhere , you may have to look up "stop asp:Button from postback" though  - it may be better to use <input type=button >   that one will work for sure , I am not sure if you were planning on handeling the click event in the code behind though after the modal dialog - so I don't know whats best for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It prevents the post back using jQuery. I have had issues with the return false method in the past.

```
$(function () {
    $("[id$=Button1]").click(function () {
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        event.preventDefault();
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Also consider using some other HTML object if the ASP.Net functionality isn't needed for the button click. It can clean stuff up quite a bit and prevents you from having to fight with the server.

Comment: I guess I don't need that function, as I can use an onclick event. Good ideas though.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the asp:button? Ie is there some server side logic that is being done as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(function () {
        modalPosition();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            modalPosition();
        });
        $('.openModal').click(function (e) {
            $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeIn('fast');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
            $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
    function modalPosition() {
        var width = $('.modal').width();
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        var x = (pageWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
        $('.modal').css({ left: x + "px" });
    }
```

Refer:- [Modal popup using jquery in asp.net](http://jqueryasp.net/modal-popup-using-jquery-asp-net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <center><h2>Product Information</h2></center>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="txtpname" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="txtpprice" placeholder="Product Price" class="form-control">
                </div>

            <input type="submit" id="btninsert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <table id="ProductTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Product Name</td>
                        <td>Product Price</td>
                        <td>Action</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mmd" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h3>Update Product</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnID" value="0" />

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="txtuppname" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="txtuppprice" placeholder="Product Price" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnupdate" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please also provide an explanation how this solves the problem